# Aggregate mediator not working when using blocking call

Tags: wso2

I am using call mediator with blocking = true to call another proxy inside a iterate mediator. When I am trying to use aggregate mediator, the aggregate mediator is not executing.

Could anyone advice me on this? Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this simply does not seem to work. We have run into the same problem multiple times, and plenty of sources about iterate/aggregate mention not using blocking calls because they won't work. [1](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/iterate-and-aggregate-mediators-with-call-mediator-in-wso2-esb) [2](https://medium.com/@naduni_pamudika/iterate-and-aggregate-mediators-with-the-send-mediator-f1e3a80d2d8d)

In previous versions this actually caused an [error](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2284) to occur, this seems to be fixed but aggregate still does not work when using blocking calls in the iterate mediator.

Is there a specific reason you are using a blocking call? If not consider using the call mediator in non-blocking mode.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are making a call to third party web service from the other proxy. Only one call can be made at a time to the web service otherwise error will be thrown. Hence the call to the other proxy can be made only after the response is returned from the proxy. So we are using blocking call.